# Swift set equatable sometimes true sometimes false

Tags: swift, set, equality

I have a struct conforming to Hashable. This model is put in a `Set`. Randomly when I check if the set contains the model it returns true/false. Why is this?

```
enum Feature: String {
    case a
    case b
}

struct FeatureState: Hashable {
    let feature: Feature
    let isEnabled: Bool
}

extension FeatureState: Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: FeatureState, rhs: FeatureState) -> Bool {
        lhs.feature == rhs.feature
    }
}

let fs1 = FeatureState(feature: .a, isEnabled: false)
let fs2 = FeatureState(feature: .a, isEnabled: true)

featureStates.insert(fs1)
print(featureStates.contains(fs2)) // sometimes true, sometimes false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set.contains` uses hashes to check whether an element is already part of the `Set` or not and only uses the `==` operator if the hash values of two elements are the same. Because of this, you need to provide your own  `hash(into:)` implementation to make the hash value only dependant on `feature`, but not `isEnabled`.

```
struct FeatureState {
    let feature: Feature
    let isEnabled: Bool
}

extension FeatureState: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: FeatureState, rhs: FeatureState) -> Bool {
        lhs.feature == rhs.feature
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(feature)
    }
}
```

Comment: Spend hours trying to find why a legacy test didn't work anymore. Thanks a lot i had no clue about this :o